# How to read a textfile in javascript and create an object

Tags: javascript, file

I would like to create objects in javascript by giving them the attributes out of a textfile but I don't know how to do this.

I would like to know how to read a text file and how to get the information of one line, creating an object "Punkt" with them and then go into the next line of the textfile. I really can't figure out how to do this...

```js
function Punkt(name, x, y, check, distanz) {
  this.name = name;
  this.x = x; //Längengrad
  this.y = y; //Breitengrad
  this.check = check;
  this.distanz = distanz;
}

var array = new Array();

var Dresden = new Punkt("Dresden", 13.7372621, 51.0504088, false, 0);
array.push(Dresden);
var Muenchen = new Punkt("München", 11.581981, 48.135125, false, 0);
array.push(Muenchen);
var Berlin = new Punkt("Berlin", 13.404954, 52.520007, false, 0);
array.push(Berlin);
```

Comment: Do you mean a textfile on the server? Or on the user's computer? Is it a CSV? JSON? Assuming you've read the CSV file: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/7bnqaxjs/

Comment: @ChrisG Uhm, it should be a txt file but i guess csv is also good. And i would like to read a file in a folder where the index is also in.
And how can i read a CSV file?

Comment: If the file is hosted next to the index, just use `fetch("cities.txt").then(r => r.text()).then(setup);` where `setup` is a function accepting the text file contents as parameter. A [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example) is a specific kind of text file used to store table data in a text-only format. How you can parse CSV contents is what the fiddle demonstrates.

Comment: And when the file is hosted in a sub folder like "website/csv/cities.txt" then i would do it like fetch(".csv/cities.txt" - right?
And would it be "const CSV = fetch("cities.txt").then(r => r.text()).then(setup);"?

Comment: You'd use `/csv/cities.txt`, but yes (the important thing is that it needs to be a valid URL, not a server-side path; JS has no direct access to files on the server, only via URLs). And no, that line won't work because `fetch` is asynchronous. you'd only store the Promise in `CSV`, not the file contents. Note that all of these are easily solved separate problems with lots of existing answers.